# Smarty or Twig for Yii2 PHPStorm integration

Tags: php, twig, yii2, smarty

If i use simple php files for view (default Yii2 style) - i can completely control what methods and properties being used atm.

But i need to write widgets to generate html or write things like this:

```
<?php foreach ($models as $news) : ?>
<!-- html code here -->
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Both things is completely bad in terms of supporting the code.

And the problem is - it seems that i can't use template engines either. Code becomes cleaner much more understandable and maintainable at first, but i lose consistency. I can't use code completion or use refactoring tools or things like "find usages". So eventually this will lead to the same problem - difficulty of supporting the code and further development.

So, is there a way for refactoring tools work on Smarty/Twig templates? Or some completely different solution to separate PHP code from views?

Comment: so, what is your question?

Comment: edited, lol, forgot to metion